# Delete Table Row not working properly with search bar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-component

i'm new to reactjs and i'm trying to make a table that shows the information from a array of objects and have a button of delete and an input to search among the users. The delete button is working correctly when i'm not searching anything, but when i'm searching it doesn't delete the corretly row, and deletes only the first one. I see that it is because the arrays that show the table are different with and without the search being used but I don't know how to make it work.

this is the component of the table:

```
import { formatDate } from "../../utils/formatDate";
import "./table.css";
import { useState } from "react";

function Table(props) {
  const { headerData, bodyData, type, removeItem} = props;
  const isUser = type === "user";

  const buildTableItems = () => {
    return bodyData.map((item, index) => (
      <tr className="data-tr">
        <td>{item.name}</td>
        <td>{item.email}</td>
        <td>{item.occupation}</td>
        <td>{formatDate(item.birthday)}</td>
        <td>
          <button className="delete-button" onClick={() => removeItem(index)}>
            Delete
          </button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    ));
  };
  return (
    <div className="user-data">
      <table className="user-table">
        <thead>
          <tr className="data-th">
            {headerData.map((headerTable) => (
              <th >{headerTable}</th>
            ))}
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>{buildTableItems()}</tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Table;
```

Here the component of the search bar:

```
import "./searchBar.css"

function SearchBar({ searchedData, onSearch }) {
  return (
    <div className="search-bar">
      <label>Search</label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Search User" value={searchedData} onChange={e => onSearch(e.target.value)} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default SearchBar;
```

and here is the home:

```
import "./Home.css";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Header from "../components/Header/Header";
import Table from "../components/Table/Table";
import AddData from "../components/AddData/AddData";
import SearchBar from "../components/SearchBar/SearchBar";
import { userArr } from "../mock/users";

const Home = () => {
  const headerUser = ["Name", "Email", "Occupation", "Birthday"];
  const [newUserArr, setNewUserArr] = useState(userArr);
  const [searchedItem, setSearchedItem] = useState("");

  const searchedArray = newUserArr.filter((item) => {
    if (item.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchedItem.toLowerCase())) {
      return true;
    }
  });
  function onSearch(e) {
    setSearchedItem(e);
  }

  const addDataToArr = (form) => {
    setNewUserArr([...newUserArr, form]);
  };

  const deleteData = (indexUserArr) => {
    let restOfDataArray = newUserArr.filter(
      (element, ind) => ind !== indexUserArr
      );
      setNewUserArr(restOfDataArray);
    };

  return (
    <>
      <Header  />
      <SearchBar searchedData={searchedItem} onSearch={onSearch} />
      <Table
        type="user"
        headerData={headerUser}
        bodyData={newUserArr}
        removeItem={(index) => deleteData(index)}
        
      />
      <AddData saveData={(val) => addDataToArr(val)} />
    </>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

thank you

Comment: You don't have id in your data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If you have ID in your user data then use that instead of index or create id keywords using concatenate with your values here is examples.**

```
import { formatDate } from "../../utils/formatDate";
import "./table.css";
import { useState } from "react";

function Table(props) {
  const { headerData, bodyData, type, removeItem} = props;
  const isUser = type === "user";

  const buildTableItems = () => {
    return bodyData.map((item, index) => (
      <tr className="data-tr">
        <td>{item.name}</td>
        <td>{item.email}</td>
        <td>{item.occupation}</td>
        <td>{formatDate(item.birthday)}</td>
        <td>
          <button className="delete-button" onClick={() => removeItem(`${item.name}${item.email}${item.occupation}`)}>
            Delete
          </button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    ));
  };
  return (
    <div className="user-data">
      <table className="user-table">
        <thead>
          <tr className="data-th">
            {headerData.map((headerTable) => (
              <th >{headerTable}</th>
            ))}
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>{buildTableItems()}</tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Table;
```

And here is your delete method `${item.name}${item.email}${index}`

```
const deleteData = (data) => {
    let restOfDataArray = newUserArr.filter(
      (element, ind) => `${element.name}${element.email}${element.occupation}` !== data
      );
      setNewUserArr(restOfDataArray);
    };
```

This will fixed your problem. If this doesn't work then you need to use ID to resolve this problem. There is a possibility that `${item.name}${item.email}${item.occupation}` can be duplicates.

**Never use index ever for deleting or any other operations. Use always ID.**

Comment: It worked, the problem was the index as you said. Thank you very much